# Converting image in database to image on pdf

Tags: node.js, image, pdfkit

I am using node JS, express and MS Sql Server. I store users signature in a signature table as VARBINARY(MAX). I am creating a pdf using pdfkit and want to place the relevant signatures from the database in the fields on the pdf file. I have a stored procedure which loads all the correct signatures from the database, but I am not sure how to convert this data to an image. What I am trying at the moment is below. I then want to send the image (sign2, for example) to the function which uses pdfkit to create the pdf file. The error here is that "the argument must be an instance of Blob".

In my main function in the server.js:

```
const resultSigns = await pool.request()
    .input('IncidentID', Number(req.body.id))
    .execute(`Read_IncidentSignatures_SP`);
const signatures = resultSigns.recordset;

let sign1 = '';
let sign2 = '';

for (const sign of signatures) {
    if (sign.SignaturePos === 1) {
        // ...
    } else if (sign.SignaturePos === 2) {
        sign2 = getImage(sign.Signature);
    } 
}


function getImage(blob) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
      let img = new Image()
      img.onload = () => {
        URL.revokeObjectURL(url)
        resolve(img)
      }
      img.src = url
    })
  }
```